# Android studio error after changing api

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-styles

> Error:resource style/Base.V21.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar (aka
>   'packagename':style/Base.V21.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar) not found.
>   Error:failed linking references.
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Failed to execute aapt

I have done nothing but change minSdk to 21, I was developing on minSdk, target and compile set at 26.

After encountering multiple errors, i decide to revert my decision by changing minSdk to 26 and i encounter this error.
I decide to use a backup copy of project in which i didn't change the version and to my pleasant surprise i encounter this again.

Any help would be appreciated.
:)

My dependencies if they're required:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
}
```

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding your project from gradle

Comment: cleaning and rebuilding wont help :(

Comment: try Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Invalidated caches and restarted, got the R error,not the original error so i rebuilt the project and we're back to same old problem

Comment: it's possible your gradle cache got corrupted, try deleting it (~/.gradle/caches)

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing issues you can switch back to previous version by adding this in gradle.properties try this

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: this gives >Error:(17, 5) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V21.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar'.